# Unable to access components from an Instantiated GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculusquest

Hi guys hopefully someone can help me or point me in the right direction. I am creating a 3D application using the Oculus quest 2 that generates a circle of 3D balls this balls are going to be exploded by the user in a specific order. The user ill kno which ball need to exploded because it will be blue and the other balls will be gray. I have created a connection using a tcp socket with a java aplication so that the doctor can state the number of balls. This balls are created using the Instantiate method. My problem comes when I want to access one instantiated ball from a script which is attached to another ball and change the color. I have encountered two problems: the first one is that when the controllers collide with the balls the game freezes for 2-4 seconds like some kind of lag happened and the second one is that i seemed to not be able to access to the list of balls. Below you have the script that connects with the application and the creation of the balls:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System;

public class Connection : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Conexion socket
    private Socket socket;
    private Socket receive;
    private IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint;
    
    private int balls = 0;

    private byte[] bufferBalls = new byte[4];

    private byte[] buffer;

    public GameObject ball;

    public Material[] material;

    public GameObject spawn;

    private int bName = 0;

    [SerializeField]
    public List<GameObject> ballsSpawned = new List<GameObject>();


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        this.startServer();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(this.receive != null)
        {
            this.receive.BeginReceive(this.bufferBalls, 0, this.bufferBalls.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveBalls), this.receive);               
        }
    }
    
    private void startServer()
    {
        this.socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        this.remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 6000);

        this.socket.Bind(this.remoteEndPoint);
        this.socket.Listen(1);
        this.socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptClient), null);
       
    }

    private void acceptClient(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        this.receive = this.socket.EndAccept(result);
        byte[] data = new byte[100];
        data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Oculus Quest 2 Connected");
        this.receive.Send(data);
        
    }

    private void receiveBalls(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        if(this.balls != 0)
        {
            this.destroyBalls();
        }

        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            Array.Reverse(this.bufferBalls);
        }
        this.balls = BitConverter.ToInt32(this.bufferBalls, 0);
        Debug.Log("Las bolas son: " + this.balls.ToString());
        this.buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Data Received correctly");

        this.algBalls();
    }

    public void algBalls()
    {
        float angle = 360 / this.balls;
        float angleCumu = 0;
        float angleAux = 180;
        System.Random ran = new System.Random();
        double range = 0.8 - 0.4;
        double radius;
        do
        {
            radius = Math.Round(ran.NextDouble() * range, 2);
        }
        while (radius < 0.1);

        float center = 0.9f;
        int i = 0;

        if(this.balls%2 == 0)
        {
            this.balls += 1;
        }

        do
        {
            double x1 = 0;
            double y1 = center + radius * Math.Sin(angleCumu);
            double z1 = center + radius * Math.Cos(angleCumu);

            Vector3 pos1 = new Vector3();
            pos1.x = (float) x1;
            pos1.y = (float) y1;
            pos1.z = (float) z1;

            this.placeBall(pos1);

            if(angleCumu == 0)
            {
                double x2 = 0;
                double y2 = center + radius * Math.Sin(angleAux);
                double z2 = center + radius * Math.Cos(angleAux);

                Vector3 pos2 = new Vector3();
                pos2.x = (float) x2;
                pos2.y = (float) y2;
                pos2.z = (float) z2;
                
                i += 2;

                this.placeBall(pos2);
                angleCumu += angle;
                continue;
            }
            double x3 = 0;
            double y3 = center + radius * Math.Sin(-angleCumu);
            double z3 = center + radius * Math.Cos(-angleCumu);

            Vector3 pos3 = new Vector3();
            pos3.x = (float) x3;
            pos3.y = (float) y3;
            pos3.z = (float) z3;

            this.placeBall(pos3);
            angleCumu += angle;
            i += 2;
        }
        while (i < this.balls);

        this.generatePair();
        this.setFirstBallActive();
    }

    private void placeBall(Vector3 pos)
    {
        ItemBall ib = new ItemBall();
        
        var a = Instantiate(this.ball, pos, Quaternion.identity);
        a.name = "Bola " + this.bName;
        a.AddComponent<ItemBall>();
        ballsSpawned.Add(a);
    }

    public void setFirstBallActive()
    {
        this.ballsSpawned[0].GetComponent<Renderer>().material = material[0];
    }

    public void destroyBalls()
    {
        foreach(var b in this.ballsSpawned)
        {
            Destroy(b);
        }
        this.ballsSpawned.Clear();
    }

    private void generatePair()
    {
        int i = 0;
        Debug.Log("Llego aqui");
        foreach(var ballA in this.ballsSpawned)
        {
            foreach(var ballB in this.ballsSpawned)
            {
                if((ballA.GetComponent<Transform>().position.z + ballB.GetComponent<Transform>().position.z) == 0 && (ballA.GetComponent<Transform>().position.y + ballB.GetComponent<Transform>().position.y) == 0)
                {
                    this.ballsSpawned[i].GetComponent<ItemBall>().ballPrefab = ballA;
                    this.ballsSpawned[i].GetComponent<ItemBall>().paired = ballB;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    public void paintBall()
    {
        foreach(var ball in this.ballsSpawned)
        {
            ball.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = material[1];
        }
    }
}
```

In the script below I simply try to change all the balls to red. I know that the hands and the balls are interacting because if I inactive them one by one they deactivate, but for some reason I am not able to access this method from the Functionality script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Functionality : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material[] materials;
    public GameObject cam;
    public GameObject Spawn;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private void Awake()
    {

    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Hand"))
        {
            cam.GetComponent<Connection>().paintBall();
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully someone knows why this is happening!!!